# Google's "Beat the boot"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas

I just came across

## [this](http://beattheboot.appspot.com/)

It looks pretty awesome so i of course went *right click and inspect element* but all i saw was a bunch of `script` tags and one single `canvas` tag with text saying "*This game is built for Google Chrome*".

[image]

Why can't i see what is happening in the html? and do you have a rough idea of how they built this?

Comment: It's all in the JavaScript includes

Comment: @Dan Diplo. The question is why can't you see the HTML code for all the animation on the screen. It is true that it's the JS that drives the canvas based animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is built using the [Canvas html element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_%28HTML_element%29) which just a bitmap with immediate mode drawing. There are no DOM elements in their to inspect just pixels.

Their code (like video games) will have some sort of loop that will draw new frames to the canvas.

Comment: I see, i was confused because i have seen other canvas implementations and they usually have more going on than just an empty canvas tag.

Comment: If you place content inside of a canvas tag it will only be displayed in browsers which don't support canvas.

Answer (score 0):

They are using Canvas:  "is a new HTML element which can be used to draw graphics using scripting". An excellent tutorial on canvas can be found on the Mozilla developer pages: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial